# How to make `git log --stat -- <path>` show *all* files in selected commits?

Tags: git

When I use a `<path>` argument with `git log --stat` to limit the log to
commits modifying `<path>`, git lists `<path>` as the only modified file when
displaying the selected commits.  I would instead like to see *all* modified
paths listed for each selected commit.

For example:

```
$ echo test > a.txt
$ echo test > b.txt
$ git add a.txt b.txt
$ git commit -m test
 [...]
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 [...]
$ git log -n1 --stat
 [...]

 a.txt |    1 +
 b.txt |    1 +
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ git log -n1 --stat -- a.txt
 [...]

 a.txt |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Note that the second `git log`, with the path argument `a.txt`, says
"1 files changed", when in fact "2 files changed".  I would like git
to tell me that both `a.txt` and `b.txt` changed, even though I
selected the commit based on the path `a.txt`.

UPDATE: @jacknagel answered my question, but it turns out his solution doesn't work in my real use case.  In my real use case, I'm looking for all commits that modified a file, including renames, in a case where two related projects diverged.  I need to figure out what changes in one project imply corresponding changes (I need to make) in the other project.  Unfortunately, `git` complains when I try to use `--full-diff` and `--follow` at the same time.

So, in my real situation, I'm trying to run:

```
git log --stat --follow -- a.txt
```

and a solution that works in this case is:

```
git log --format='%H' --follow -- a.txt | xargs git show --stat -C
```

Comment: What ever you ask doesn't make much sense to me. How do you expect a command to behave in a different way than it is intended to do? When you give the filename you are telling git to get the details of that file alone. If you want it to show both the stuff then use the command

Comment: @positron: I'm using the file name to identify commits of interests, but for those commits I want the full information.  In essence, I'm using the given file name to identify other *unknown* file names of interest.  So, I can't tell `git` the other files, because I don't know what they are.

Comment: Instead of editing your *question* to append an answer, the StackOverflow way is to add an answer, even if it's your own question. I've taken the liberty of adding the correct answer, but I'll gladly delete it if you post it yourself

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get this behavior using the `--full-diff` option:

```
   --full-diff
       Without this flag, "git log -p <path>..." shows commits that touch
       the specified paths, and diffs about the same specified paths. With
       this, the full diff is shown for commits that touch the specified
       paths; this means that "<path>..." limits only commits, and doesn't
       limit diff for those commits.

       Note that this affects all diff-based output types, e.g. those
       produced by --stat etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question I asked and so I'm accepting the answer. However, it turns out my question was not specific enough, and `--full-diff` doesn't work in my real situation, where I'm using `--follow`.  I'll update the question and add a solution that works with `--follow` in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

First find the commit ids, then pipe them to `xargs` (or gnu `parallel`) to feed each id to `git show`.

```
git log --format='%H' --follow -- a.txt | xargs git show --stat -C
```

On windows with powershell, something like this should work (but I haven't tested it yet..):

```
git log --format='%H' --follow -- a.txt | ForEach-Object { git show --stat -C $_ }
```

Answer (score -2):

How do you expect a command to behave in a different way than it is intended to do? When you give the filename you are telling git to get the details of that file alone. If you want it to show both the files then use the command

```
git log -n1 --stat .
```

or

```
git log -n1 --stat a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: I think the idea is to say to git "show me only commits that touch <path>, but when showing those commits, list everything they did".